# C#/WPF NullReference Exception on filling Rectangle with App Settings Value

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, nullreferenceexception, rectangles

I'm trying to fill a `rectangle` with a Value of the `settings.settings`. But it throws an NullRefference error. When I show the setting with a MessageBox, it isnt empty. The `NullRefference exception` is triggerd by the Rectangle

```
 var rect = btnBackground.Template.FindName("rectBackground", btnBackground) as Rectangle;
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((PawnStar.Properties.Settings.Default.colorBG)));                                            // PawnStar.Properties.Settings.Default.colorBG
        colorBG = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((PawnStar.Properties.Settings.Default.colorBG));
```

WPF:

```
<Button Click="btnBackground_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="btnBackground">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Name="rectBackground" Stroke="Black" Fill="#FFFFFF"></Rectangle>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
```

When I create a new Rectangle object, I can't change the color anymore.

Comment: Where do you place the first code snippet?

Comment: In Window_Loaded. But even when I place it in the SelectionChanged Event of my TabControl, it crashes

Comment: What's the value of `colorBG`? are you sure you store it correctly with correct/convertible color string value?

Comment: Can you not use `TemplateBinding` on `Rectangle` `Fill` to use `Button`'s `Backgound`? and then it would be easier to update Button's `Background`, which in-turn updates Rectangle's `Fill`.

Comment: Correct way for `TemplateBinding` `<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="rectBackground" Stroke="Black"  />`

Comment: Thanks that works. Please answer the question so that I can mark it as answered

Comment: Note that using `Binding` is just a convenient way, your problem may relate to some `converting` failure. I doubt that the default `colorBG` is empty or contains string which is unconvertible to `Color`, such as `Rad` won't be converted to `Colors.Red` as you thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying is to have a `TemplateBinding` on `Rectangle` `Fill` property to use `Button's` `Background`. And then, set background of button to your value from app settings, which in-turn will update Rectangle's Fill

Sample Code as below:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="rectBackground" Stroke="Black" />
```